# Qual o uso correto do operador "in", em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Esse código não retorna nada, por quê? Estou executando em evento "window.onload":

```
if(innerHeight in window){
     console.log('true');
}
```

Eu já havia usado o operador outras vezes, e funcionava, mas agora me veio essa... E então, alguém pode me ajudar aqui?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
'innerHeight' in window
```

Como estás à procura de uma propriedade deves usar uma *String*, senão é como se estivesses à procura do conteúdo da variável `innerHeight` em `window`, ou seja o que tens é:

```
var alturaEmPixeis = windows.innerHeight; // isto é um numero
if (alturaEmPixeis in window){
```

e devias ter

```
if ('innerHeight' in window){
```

para saber se o objeto `window` tem a propriedade de nome `innerHeight`.

Comment: Obrigado, Sergio! =)